# Unsupervised Anomaly Detection with Mixed Numeric and Categorical Data

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-mining, data-analysis

I am working on a data analysis project over the summer. The main goal is to use some access logging data in the hospital about user accessing patient information and try to detect abnormal accessing behaviors. Several attributes have been chosen to characterize a user (e.g. employee role, department, zip-code) and a patient (e.g. age, sex, zip-code). There are about 13 - 15 variables under consideration.

I was using R before and now I am using Python. I am able to use either depending on any suitable tools/libraries you guys suggest.

Before I ask any question, I do want to mention that a lot of the data fields have undergone an anonymization process when handed to me, as required in the healthcare industry for the protection of personal information. Specifically, a lot of VARCHAR values are turned into random integer values, only maintaining referential integrity across the dataset.

Questions:

- An exact definition of an outlier was not given (it's defined based on the behavior of most of the data, if there's a general behavior) and there's no labeled training set telling me which rows of the dataset are considered abnormal. I believe the project belongs to the area of unsupervised learning so I was looking into clustering.

  Since the data is mixed (numeric and categorical), I am not sure how would clustering work with this type of data.

  I've read that one could expand the categorical data and let each category in a variable to be either 0 or 1 in order to do the clustering, but then how would R/Python handle such high dimensional data for me? (simply expanding employer role would bring in ~100 more variables)

---

- How would the result of clustering be interpreted?

  Using clustering algorithm, wouldn't the potential "outliers" be grouped into clusters as well? And how am I suppose to detect them?

  Also, with categorical data involved, I am not sure how "distance between points" is defined any more and does the proximity of data points indicate similar behaviors? Does expanding each category into a dummy column with true/false values help? What's the distance then?

---

- Faced with the challenges of cluster analysis, I also started to try slicing the data up and just look at two variables at a time. For example, I would look at the age range of patients accessed by a certain employee role, and I use the quartiles and inter-quartile range to define outliers. For categorical variables, for instance, employee role and types of events being triggered, I would just look at the frequency of each event being triggered.

  Can someone explain to me the problem of using quartiles with data that's not normally distributed? And what would be the remedy of this?

---

- And in the end, which of the two approaches (or some other approaches) would you suggest? And what's the best way to use such an approach?
  Thanks a lot.

Comment: First off I like the question.  Having a bit of healthcare data background myself though I'd probably point out that too many variables in this case might be your enemy, and I think there are two distinct questions in the data set.  One; is the data being looked at pertinent to the user. Two, are specific individuals looking at too much.  I don't know all of your variables but my guess is you can probably shrink the set down a bit.  I would look at the patient Unit/Dept vs the user Unit/Dept or in case of a physician specialty.  You'll see some variables present like OBGYN and Peds

Comment: Those questions are of interest. However, from what I've discussed with my teammates, slicing the data and seeing that a point is off in the 2D space would not mean that it's an abnormal piece of data in the original k-dimensional space. Don't you think so?

Comment: Perhaps, but I guess if the diving motivation for the request is compliance based then you have some black and white in terms of the "Who is allowed to look at what" versus user experience overall when the question is "How are they navigating the EMR"

Comment: @Pakwah did you ever figure this out? I have a similar problem and would like to know your process.

Answer (score 0):

You can decide upon a similarity measure for mixed data (e.g. Gower distance).

Then you can use any of the distance-based outlier detection methods.

Comment: Now that I review the variables that I want to consider, I think all of them can be treated as categorical variables, and I think I am going to create a dummy column for every category so that the value is either 0 or 1.         And then I want to perform PCA to see if there are clusters in the dimensionally reduced data. Do you think PCA would work for all binary columns and such high dimensional data?(couple hundreds) @Anony-Mousse

Comment: No, I don't think it will work PCA is for continuos variables, with continuous correlations. If you have binary data, you may be able to find patterns by doing market basket analysis (which expects binary occurences)

Comment: What if I change every category in a column to a number and do it to all categorical columns, and then I can use z-score to standardize all the columns to make them in the same scale. Do you think this will work for PCA and clustering even if the number assignments are arbitrary? (It will maintain referential integrity)

Comment: No. Adding more random functions doesn't make the approach sensible. Z-score is motivated by *normal* distributed data. Binary values are not normal. Try to figure out what is sensible, not what is programmable. There are too many things to try that do not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use k-prototypes algorithm for mixed numeric and categorical attributes. 
[Here](https://github.com/nicodv/kmodes) you can find a python implementation.